# how to get distance from two locations name using php

Tags: php, location

I have php code that returns `$distance` value using location number but how to get distance using location name?
here Code

```
$from = "Arlington Heights, IL 60005, United States";
$to = 'Arlington Heights, IL 60004, United States';
$from = urlencode($from);
$to = urlencode($to);
$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);
$time = 0;
$distance = 0;

foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
    $time += $road->duration->value;
    $distance += $road->distance->value;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "location number"? As far as I can see, you are using actual place names in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it looks like I was wrong about comma's, but take onboard that their not needed for this query and could cause errors especially if your relying on user input. I believe your issue is down to your `foreach()` loop as in it's not really needed if your just querying **A** to **B**. Also, your querying the array like it's an object which it is not. You need to use square brackets `[]` when querying specific elements in an array.

```
$from = 'Arlington Heights, IL 60005, United States';
$remFrom = str_replace(',', '', $from); //Remove Commas
$from = urlencode($remFrom);

$to = 'Arlington Heights, IL 60004, United States';
$remTo = str_replace(',', '', $to); //Remove Commas
$to = urlencode($remTo);

$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

$time = $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']; //Text for String and Value for INT
$distance = $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];//Text for String and Value for INT

echo 'Distance: ' . $distance . '<br>';
echo 'Time: ' . $time;
```

**Output:**

```
Distance: 5.7 km
Time: 11 mins
```

See:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: It works fine with commas, so that isn't the problem. `urlencode` takes care of that

Comment: Thanks but information comes from input text so how can I remove coma?

Comment: @GhadahSalman comma's will pass after `urlencode()` but their not needed. I would personally remove all non-word characters apart from spaces. The code above explains how to do this using `str_replace()`, just set the `$from` & `$to` variable to contain your user input variable.

Comment: thanks @Kitson88 working fine but replace $data = json_decode($data); > $data = json_decode($data,true);

Comment: @GhadahSalman  No worries and My bad... I must of forgot to set it as an associative array when transplanting into Stack.